# Como iterar um array recursivo sem redundância?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Tenho em determinado diretório, milhares de arquivos de pacote de software, que por sua vez tem versões, como por exemplo:

```
/var/cache/fetch/archives/python-3.5.0-1-x86_64.chi.zst
/var/cache/fetch/archives/python-3.8.6-1-x86_64.chi.zst
/var/cache/fetch/archives/python-3.8.6-2-x86_64.chi.zst
/var/cache/fetch/archives/nano-5.0-1-x86_64.chi.zst
/var/cache/fetch/archives/nano-5.2-1-x86_64.chi.zst
/var/cache/fetch/archives/nano-5.3-1-x86_64.chi.zst
```

A cada nova versão, necessito compilar e empacotar os mesmos, removendo as versão mais antigas do diretório, o qual escrevi esse script abaixo para a função de remover as versões mais antigas, deixando somente a versão mais atual.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

aPKGSPLIT=()
cachedirs=("/var/cache/fetch/archives")
pkg_ext='.chi.zst'
pkg_re='(.+)-(([^-]+)-([0-9]+))-([^.]+)\.chi\.zst'
: ${aPKGSPLIT=()}
: ${aPKGLIST=}
: ${PKG_FOLDER_DIR=0}
: ${PKG_FULLNAME=1}
: ${PKG_ARCH=2}
: ${PKG_BASE=3}
: ${PKG_BASE_VERSION=4}
: ${PKG_VERSION=5}
: ${PKG_BUILD=6}

function die(){
    local msg=$1; shift
   printf "%s %s\n" "$msg" "$@" >&2
    exit 1
}

sh_splitpkg(){
    local file=${1}
    local pkg_folder_dir=$(echo ${file%/*})
    local pkg_fullname=$(echo ${file##*/})
    local   pkg_base=
    local   pkg_version_build=
    local   pkg_version=
    local   pkg_build=
    local   pkg_arch=
    local   pkg_base_version=

    [[ $pkg_fullname =~ $pkg_re ]] &&
        pkg_fullname=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
        pkg_base=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        pkg_version_build=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        pkg_version=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        pkg_build=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
        pkg_arch=${BASH_REMATCH[5]}
        pkg_base_version=${pkg_base}-${pkg_version_build}

    aPKGSPLIT=($pkg_folder_dir $pkg_fullname $pkg_arch $pkg_base $pkg_base_version $pkg_version $pkg_build)
    return $?
}

main(){
    local pkg=
    local pkgInAll=
    local pkg_base=
    local pkg_search=
    local candidates=()
    local cachedir

    for cachedir in "${cachedirs[@]}"
    do
        [[ -d $cachedir ]]            || die "Error: cachedir '$cachedir' does not exist or is not a directory"
        pushd "$cachedir" &>/dev/null || die "Error: failed to chdir to $cachedir"

        while read -r pkgInAll;do
            sh_splitpkg ${pkgInAll}
            pkg_base=${aPKGSPLIT[$PKG_BASE]}

            [[ -z "$pkg_base" ]] && continue

            while read -r pkg;do
                sh_splitpkg ${pkg}
                pkg_search=${aPKGSPLIT[$PKG_BASE]}

                [[ -z "$pkg_search" ]] &&   continue
                [[ "${pkg_search::1}" > "${pkg_base::1}" ]] && break

                if [[ "${pkg_base}" =~ "${pkg_search}" ]] && [[ "$(vercmp $pkgInAll $pkg)" -lt 0 ]]; then
                    printf "%s\n" "${pkgInAll}"
                    candidates+=("${pkgInAll}")
                fi
            done < <(printf '%s\n' "$(find "$PWD" -type f -name "$pkg_base*.zst" | grep -E "*$pkg_base-([0-9])" | sort)")
        done < <(printf '%s\n' "$(find "$PWD" -type f -name "*.chi.zst" | sort)")
        popd >/dev/null 2>&1
    done

    if (( ! ${#candidates[*]} )); then
        die "NO packages found for pruning"
    fi
}

main $*
```

O script cumpre bem a tarefa, pecando somente na questão de rapidez, sendo que são milhares de pacotes a processar, pois necessário verificar individualmente cada um deles com outro pacote para saber qual versão é mais atual.

Alguma ideia para melhorar a rapidez dessa busca?

nessa parte do código foi usado o find, pois os pacotes também se encontram em subdiretórios:

```
done < <(printf '%s\n' "$(find "$PWD" -type f -name "*.chi.zst" | sort)")
```

O cerne da questão é de como melhorar esse processamento abaixo:

```
    while read -r pkgInAll;do
        sh_splitpkg ${pkgInAll}
        pkg_base=${aPKGSPLIT[$PKG_BASE]}

        [[ -z "$pkg_base" ]] && continue

        while read -r pkg;do
            sh_splitpkg ${pkg}
            pkg_search=${aPKGSPLIT[$PKG_BASE]}

            [[ -z "$pkg_search" ]] &&   continue
            [[ "${pkg_search::1}" > "${pkg_base::1}" ]] && break

            if [[ "${pkg_base}" =~ "${pkg_search}" ]] && [[ "$(vercmp $pkgInAll $pkg)" -lt 0 ]]; then
                printf "%s\n" "${pkgInAll}"
                candidates+=("${pkgInAll}")
            fi
        done < <(printf '%s\n' "$(find "$PWD" -type f -name "$pkg_base*.zst" | grep -E "*$pkg_base-([0-9])" | sort)")
    done < <(printf '%s\n' "$(find "$PWD" -type f -name "*.chi.zst" | sort)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Me inspirei no seu tema e vi nele um novo desafio.

Para ter uma melhor desempenho, você precisa chamar o menor número possível de processos.

Eu criei um script que:

1. Constrói um diretório de arquivo com arquivos fictícios como exemplo e os mostra,
2. Aplique o algoritmo para excluir as versões antigas de todos os pacotes para cada arquitetura (descartando arquivos que não correspondam ao padrão de nome do arquivo),
3. Mostra os arquivos restantes (ou seja, as últimas versões).

Depois de brincar com o script e entendê-lo, você pode adaptá-lo.

Abaixo está o script compatível com o Linux:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

archive_dir="archives"

[ -d "${archive_dir}" ] && rm -rf "${archive_dir}"
mkdir "${archive_dir}"
touch "${archive_dir}"/python-3.5.0-1-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/python-3.8.6-1-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/python-3.8.6-2-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/nano-5.0-1-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/nano-5.2-1-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/nano-5.3-1-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/git-2.35-1-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/git-2.35-2-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/git-2.36-1-armv7.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/git-2.37-1-armv7.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/sed-1.5.3-2-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/sed-1.5.3-2-armv7.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/sed-1.5.3-3-armv7.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/a-wrong-format-archive-to-dismiss.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/another-file-to-dismiss.txt

echo 'Initial files:'
find "${archive_dir}" -type f | sort
echo

echo 'Cleaning old versions...'
find "${archive_dir}" \
        -type f \
        -regextype posix-extended \
        -regex '^.*/(.+)-(([^-]+)-([0-9]+))-([^.]+)\.chi\.zst$' | \
    sed -Ee 's/^.*\/(.+)-(([^-.]+)\.?([^-.]+)?\.?([^-.]+)?-([0-9]+))-([^.]+)\.chi\.zst$/&|\3|\4|\5|\6|\1|\7/' \
        -Ee 's/\|\|/|0|/g' \
        -Ee 's/\|/ /g' | \
    sort -t ' ' -k 6,6 -k 7,7 -k 2nr,2 -k 3nr,3 -k 4nr,3 -k 5nr,5 | \
    uniq -f 5 --all-repeated=separate | \
    sed -Ee 's/^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)$/\1/' | \
    tr '\n' '|' | \
    sed -Ee 's/\|\|/\n/g' | \
    sed -Ee 's/^([^|]+)\|//' | \
    tr '|' '\n' | \
    xargs -r -L 1 -t rm 
echo

echo 'Remaining files:'
find "${archive_dir}" -type f | sort
```

Abaixo está o mesmo script, mas compatível com macOS (as alterações estão nos comandos `find` e `uniq`):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

archive_dir="archives"

[ -d "${archive_dir}" ] && rm -rf "${archive_dir}"
mkdir "${archive_dir}"
touch "${archive_dir}"/python-3.5.0-1-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/python-3.8.6-1-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/python-3.8.6-2-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/nano-5.0-1-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/nano-5.2-1-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/nano-5.3-1-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/git-2.35-1-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/git-2.35-2-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/git-2.36-1-armv7.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/git-2.37-1-armv7.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/sed-1.5.3-2-x86_64.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/sed-1.5.3-2-armv7.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/sed-1.5.3-3-armv7.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/a-wrong-format-archive-to-dismiss.chi.zst
touch "${archive_dir}"/another-file-to-dismiss.txt

echo 'Initial files files:'
find -E "${archive_dir}" -type f | sort
echo

echo 'Cleaning old versions...'
find -E "${archive_dir}" \
        -type f \
        -regex '^.*/(.+)-(([^-]+)-([0-9]+))-([^.]+)\.chi\.zst$' | \
    sed -Ee 's/^.*\/(.+)-(([^-.]+)\.?([^-.]+)?\.?([^-.]+)?-([0-9]+))-([^.]+)\.chi\.zst$/&|\3|\4|\5|\6|\1|\7/' \
        -Ee 's/\|\|/|0|/g' \
        -Ee 's/\|/ /g' | \
    sort -t ' ' -k 6,6 -k 7,7 -k 2nr,2 -k 3nr,3 -k 4nr,3 -k 5nr,5 | \
    uniq -f 5 -Dseparate | \
    sed -Ee 's/^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)$/\1/' | \
    tr '\n' '|' | \
    sed -Ee 's/\|\|/\n/g' | \
    sed -Ee 's/^([^|]+)\|//' | \
    tr '|' '\n' | \
    xargs -r -L 1 -t rm 
echo

echo 'Remaining files:'
find -E "${archive_dir}" -type f | sort
```

## Explicações

Obtém a lista de arquivos cujo nome corresponde ao padrão:

```bash
find "${archive-dir}" \
        -type f \
        -regextype posix-extended \
        -regex '^.*/(.+)-(([^-]+)-([0-9]+))-([^.]+)\.chi\.zst$' | \
```

A sed with 3 steps:

1. Reordena todas as linhas e constrói valores separados por tubos (e.g. `archives/nano-5.3-1-x86_64.chi.zst|5|3||1|nano|x86_64`),
2. Define as versões ausentes como 0 (substituindo `||`, por exemplo, `archives/nano-5.3-1-x86_64.chi.zst|5|3|0|1|nano|x86_64`)
3. Substitui tubos por espaços (por exemplo, `archives/nano-5.3-1-x86_64.chi.zst 5 3 0 1 nano x86_64`)

```bash
    sed -Ee 's/^.*\/(.+)-(([^-.]+)\.?([^-.]+)?\.?([^-.]+)?-([0-9]+))-([^.]+)\.chi\.zst$/&|\3|\4|\5|\6|\1|\7/' \
        -Ee 's/\|\|/|0|/g' \
        -Ee 's/\|/ /g' | \
```

Sorts every lines, using this order:

1. Nome do programa, crescente,
2. Arquitetura, crescente,
3. Componentes da versão, classificação numérica, decrescente (a versão mais recente vem primeiro).

```bash
    sort -t ' ' -k 6,6 -k 7,7 -k 2nr,2 -k 3nr,3 -k 4nr,3 -k 5nr,5 | \
```

Agrupa por pacote e arquitetura, descartando pacotes com uma única versão para uma arquitetura.
Para cada pacote de uma arquitetura, as linhas são agrupadas e os grupos são separados por uma linha em branco:

```bash
    uniq -f 5 --all-repeated=separate | \
```

Apenas mantém o caminho dos arquivos, descartando outras colunas, pois não são mais úteis:

```bash
    sed -Ee 's/^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)$/\1/' | \
```

Mescla linhas substituindo `\n` por `|` (produz uma única linha grande, onde pacotes são separados por `|`e grupos de pacotes por `||`:

```bash
    tr '\n' '|' | \
```

Substituindo `||` por `\n` (uma linha é igual a um grupo de caminhos separados por `|`):

```bash
    sed -Ee 's/\|\|/\n/g' | \
```

Removendo o primeiro caminho de arquivo de cada linha (na verdade, descartando a versão mais recente que sempre vem primeiro, graças à classificação anterior):

```bash
    sed -Ee 's/^([^|]+)\|//' | \
```

Substituindo `|` por `\n` (todos os caminhos das versões antigas a serem removidas agora estão em uma única linha):

```bash
    tr '|' '\n' | \
```

Enviando cada linha como um parâmetro do comando `rm` usando `xargs`:

```bash
    xargs -r -L 1 -t rm
```

Observe que outra otimização pode ser feita na chamada `xarg`, alterando a opção `-L 1`, que indica quantos parâmetros (ou seja, caminhos, aqui 1) você fornece ao comando `rm` ao mesmo tempo.
Quanto mais caminhos você usar, menos processos `rm` serão chamados e mais rápido será, mas você pode atingir um limite de comprimento de comando ou um limite de contagem de parâmetro...